# Gradle: Nested project structure and git submodule setup

Tags: gradle, minecraft, multi-project

I have a project structure set up for a Minecraft mod project. The layout is multiple gradle-backed projects, arranged as so:

```
root
  ├- core (git submodule)
  | ├- core
  | | └- build.gradle.kts
  | |
  | ├- core-api
  | | └- build.gradle.kts
  | |
  | ├- room-api
  | | └- build.gradle.kts
  | |
  | ├- room-upgrade-api
  | | └- build.gradle.kts
  | |
  | └- settings.gradle.kts
  |
  ├- main
  | └- build.gradle.kts
  |
  ├- datagen
  | └- build.gradle.kts
  |
  ├- settings.gradle.kts
  └- build.gradle.kts
```

**Layout Details:**

- `core` comes from a git submodule and needs to be configured that it can stand alone, as the various API projects inside are built separately for other mods.

  - `core`, `core-api`, `room-api`, and `room-upgrade-api` are all at the same level under `platform`.
  - `core` is built atop all three API projects.
  - `room-upgrade-api` is built atop `room-api`.
- `main` is the main source code, and must include all 4 platform projects.

**The Problem:**
I cannot get core (in the submodule) to reference the project structure correctly, while included as a part of an actual modloader build tree. The relative projects seem to either not be found (during the neoforge builds) or need to be included at the root as `includeBuild`.

Reference: https://github.com/robotgryphon/CompactMachines/tree/1.20.x-WIP